# Git não envia commits para servidor. Erro: Everything up-to-date

Tags: git

Ao dar o comando: git push origin master o git não envia as informações e dá o seguinte erro:

```
Everything up-to-date
```

Percebi que o `master` do meu repositório local não está apontando para o último commit, como pode ser visto na imagem abaixo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como eu posso resolver isso?
Obrigado!

Comment: Existe algum branch mais atual? Tente dar o push desse branch.

Comment: Não, é só branch Master mesmo. A questão é que eu havia revertido um commit e depois continuei a trabalhar no master e a fazer outros commits. No entanto quando eu fui enviar para o Bitbucket deu esse erro.

Comment: Se tiver certeza absoluta que seu branch está na frente do bitbucket, eu tentaria `git push -f origin master`.

Comment: Se vocês observarem o branch master (local) e o remotes/origin/master (que é o do Bitbucket) está bem atrás do meu commit atual. Por falta de conhecimento, eu fiz um reset e depois continuei a commitar, só depois vi o problema. 
yamadapc, pelo que entendi esse comando força o envio, certo? Mas o que acontece é que o que está no Bitbucket é o mesmo que está no meu branck master (ou, seja para onde ele tá apontando), como pode ser visto na imagem. O que eu preciso é apontar esse master(local) para o commit mais atual e depois eu posso enviar com o git push

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Resolvi aqui da seguinte forma:

```
git reset --hard [sua branch]
git add .
git commit -m "...blablabla"
git push origin [sua branch]
```

Obrigado a todos pela ajuda!
Abraço!

Answer (score 2):

Tava com esse erro no Mint, o problema era que o `git add -A` não estava funcionando, usando `git add *nome do arquivo*` e fazendo commit ele conseguiu dar `push`.

Answer (score 0):

Um dos motivos que isso ocorre é quando o endereço do seu repositório remoto está errado, apontando para o seu próprio repositório local.
Neste caso o código local a ser enviado sempre estará idêntico ao do destino, afinal eles são os mesmos... Certo?

Para verificar se este é o caso, execute:

```
git remote -v
```

Será exibido todos os repositórios remotos conhecidos. Verifique se o caminho remoto está correto...

Aqui vale uma observação: muitos tutoriais mandam configurar o repositório remoto com nome de "local", mas entenda que o que manda é o caminho, "local" poderia se chamar "origin", "banana", "chuchu"...

```
[user@ip-172-31-32-33 app]# git remote -v
local     /home/user/projeto-xyz (fetch)
local     /home/user/projeto-xyz (push)
```

Caso o caminho remoto não esteja correto, altere usando:

```
git remote set-url local /caminho-remoto-correto
```

Feito isso, execute novamente:

```
git push local master
```